# IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null. while using picaso & Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

a getting this error "IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null."when i am trying to load images using recylerview and picaso.

*I tried to use recylerview to display bunch of images which i was got done then i tried to use picaso to load the image load . 
*I alos tried to use "this" keyword also but this did not work .

Main Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//Dummydata or place holderdata.


final static int[] dummyImages={R.drawable.color_black,R.drawable.color_white,R.drawable.color_brown,R.drawable.color_dusty_yellow,R.drawable.color_mustard_yellow,R.drawable.color_red};
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);


    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(dummyImages);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}
```

}

My Adpater

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private String[] adumyDataSet;
private int[] adumyimage;
private Context context;


// Provide a direct reference to each of the views within a data item
// Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // Your holder should contain a member variable
    // for any view that will be set as you render a row
    public ImageView colorImageView;

    // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row.
    // and does the view lookups to find each subview
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
        // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
        super(itemView);
        colorImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorsBitch);

    }
}

public RecycleAdapter (int[] dummyDataSet){

    adumyimage=dummyDataSet;

}

@Override
public RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Picasso.with(context).load(adumyimage[position]).into(holder.colorImageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return adumyimage.length;
}
```

}

Comment: `Picasso.with(context)`. What makes you think `context` could be not null at this point?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:
Send context to adapter as a constructor

```
public RecycleAdapter (int[] dummyDataSet,Context context){
  this.context=context;
  adumyimage=dummyDataSet;

}
```

In your activity

```
mAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(dummyImages,this);
```

Comment: you cannot call getActivity() in adapter. it can be called in Fragment. And op is using AppCompatActivity

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer.. Could it work?

Comment: yo.. upvoted :)

Comment: thankyou for your help! .But it showed the same error .

Comment: It worked . i changes mAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(dummyImages,this);to mAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(dummyImages,getApplicationContext());     and it worked thank you ver much .

Comment: Hi! Please upvote my answer and make it solved.